# Applying a vectorized function with several returns to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that contains a column holding 'Log' strings.
I'd like to create a new column based on the values I've parsed from the 'Log' column.
Currently, I'm using `.apply()` with the following function:

```
def classification(row):
    if 'A' in row['Log']:
        return 'Situation A'
    elif 'B' in row['Log']:
        return 'Situation B'
    elif 'C' in row['Log']:
        return 'Situation C'
    return 'Check'
```

it looks like:
`df['Classification'] = df.apply(classification, axis=1)`
The issue is that it takes a lot of time (~3min to a dataframe with 4M rows) and I'm looking for a faster way.
I saw some examples of users using vectorized functions that run much faster but those don't have if statements in the function.
My question - is it possible to vectorize the function I've added and what is the fastest way to perform
this task?

Comment: check out `np.select`

Comment: Or you can do `df['Log'].str.exrtact('(A|B|C)').fillna('Check')`.

Comment: @QuangHoang Problem with that solution is that consider the order of the string i.e. from `AB` will extract `A` while from `BA` will extract `B`. On the other hand the OP function `classification` has an hierarchical ordering of extraction.

Comment: @Moti laluom from your profile it appears you are not aware of [someone-answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: @QuangHoang suggestion `df['Log'].str.exrtact('(A|B|C)').fillna('Check')` is excelent for my case. Wall Time is less than 3 sec.

Answer (score 2):

I would not be sure that using a nested `numpy.where` will increase performance: here some test performace with 4M rows

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

ls = ['Abc', 'Bert', 'Colv', 'Dia']
df =  pd.DataFrame({'Log': np.random.choice(ls, 4_000_000)})

df['Log_where'] = np.where(df['Log'].str.contains('A'), 'Situation A', 
                      np.where(df['Log'].str.contains('B'), 'Situation B', 
                          np.where(df['Log'].str.contains('C'), 'Situation C', 'check')))


def classification(x):
    if 'A' in x:
        return 'Situation A'
    elif 'B' in x:
        return 'Situation B'
    elif 'C' in x:
        return 'Situation C'
    return 'Check'


df['Log_apply'] = df['Log'].apply(classification)
```

**Nested np.where Performance**

```
 %timeit np.where(df['Log'].str.contains('A'), 'Situation A', np.where(df['Log'].str.contains('B'), 'Situation B',np.where(df['Log'].str.contains('C'), 'Situation C', 'check')))
8.59 s ± 1.71 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

**Applymap Performance**

```
%timeit df['Log'].apply(classification)
911 ms ± 146 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

At least with my machine using nested `np.where` is almost 10x times slower than a `applymap`.

**A final remark**: using the solution suggested in the comments, i.e. something like:

```
d = {'A': 'Situation A',
     'B': 'Situation B',
     'C': 'Situation C'}
df['Log_extract'] = df['Log'].str.extract('(A|B|C)')
df['Log_extract'] = df['Log_extract'].map(d).fillna('Check')
```

has the following problems:

1. It *won't* necessarely be faster - testing on my machine:

   ```
   %timeit df['Log_extract'] = df['Log'].str.extract('(A|B|C)')
   3.74 s ± 70.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
   ```
2. The `.extract` method follows string order i.e. from the string `'AB'` will extract `'A'` and from `'BA'` will extract `'B'`. On the other hand the OP function `classification` has an hierarchical ordering of extraction, thus extract `'A'` in both cases.